# How to scale a SkinnableContainer and all his childs in FLEX?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<s:SkinnableContainer styleName="top" width="1458" height="131" >
            <s:VGroup left="50" verticalAlign="middle" height="131" styleName="profile_info">
                <s:Image source="@Embed(source='images/logo.png')"/>
            </s:VGroup>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
```

in my application I have this:

```
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    width="800" height="600" addedToStage="stretchHandler()">

    private function stretchHandler():void{
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP;
        this.width = stage.stageWidth;
        this.height = stage.stageHeight;
    }
```

but the SkinnableContainer and the image inside doesn't scale, how to scale them?

Answer (score 0):

To have your content scale to it's container you must set height and width as a percentage EG:

```
<s:SkinnableContainer styleName="top" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

This would make your container always be the same size of its parent. However content of your container would still follow its own sizing settings.

[Layout settings](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html) are also important, in a `Group` two object set to 100% would overlap each other and which ever is higher in the `z` order will be on top. However in a `VGroup` the two items at 100%/100% would each take 50% of the height and 100% width.

Note 1: Spark Image acts like a container arround the source image, while "the container" will scale to the parent container, the source image will follow slightly different rules, you have to use `Image.fillMode` and `Image.scaleMode` to control it ([I recommend reading the docs on this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-8000.html#WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-33ad5caa12c719dc7c8-7ffb))

Note 2: All `UIComponents` have min/max hieght/width properties as well as the standard size props

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

All container width and height should be percentage(%) based and Image aswell also for image need to give `scaleMode="stretch" fillMode="scale"`.

```
<s:SkinnableContainer left="300" styleName="top" width="90%" height="40%">
            <s:Image source="@Embed(source='images/logo.png')" width="100%" height="100%" scaleMode="stretch" fillMode="scale"/>    
    </s:SkinnableContainer>
```

This will work.